# How does this Hashing function from CryEngine work?

Tags: c++, c, hash, cryengine

```
unsigned int HashString( const char *string ) {
    const char* p;
    unsigned hash = 40503;

    for ( p = string; *p != '\0'; ++p ) {
        hash += *p;
        hash += ( hash << 10 );
        hash ^= ( hash >> 6 );
    }
    hash += ( hash << 3 );
    hash ^= ( hash >> 11 );
    hash += ( hash << 15 );

    return hash;
}
```

Just wandering over their code. I've never seen a hashing function like this before though.

I'm not too seasoned when it comes to bitwise ops, I know how bit shifting and masking works, but only in a rudimentary scenario like checking if bits are set.

What exactly does this do?

Comment: It does what it says it does. What exactly is the question? Any elementary text book on either C or C++ will explain what the operators in the language are.

Comment: Google "linear feedback shift register".

Comment: @Kerrek I guess my question is how exactly does it hash well? I know what the goal of a hashing function is, but how exactly is this a good hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [here](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx) for a general overview, and go down for "One-at-a-Time hash" (by Jenkins), which coincides with this one.

Also see this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function), mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666799/277304).

"how exactly is this a good hash?" Not exactly. Those shifts are a little arbitrary, justified mostly from some heuristics and empirical tests.

Comment: Hurrah! I was hoping someone would find a good online resource on the theory.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing will be much easier to understand when you've got a broader understanding of binary arithmetic in general. It's way easier to go from the math to the code than the other way around.

I'm not having much luck finding a good online resource, but I was very happy with an earlier edition of [this textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012383872X) when I was in school. You may be able to find some online lecture notes from a good CS class on binary arithmetic as well.

[This site](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Hash_function.html) may give you a lead into hash theory in general. I wish I could recommend a textbook there, but I've yet to come across a really lucid number theory textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Who says it hashes well?

A hash function maps an input, which in this case is a string, to an output, in this case an `unsigned int`. The size of the input is `(number of usable characters) ^ number of characters in the string` where `^` is "raised to the power of".

If your input string can contain only the *characters* `0` and `1` then the size of the input would be `2^ number of characters in the string`

The size of the output is fixed, at the largest number representable in an `unsigned int`.

This means that there is a "number of characters in the string" where the size of the input will be greater than the size of the output. By the [pigeon hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) you will definitely start having collisions. In reality, you probably had collisions before this threshold is reached.

If you want to use a hash function in your `hash_map` or any other data structure, make sure it is tuned to your specific input. Don't go picking up the first one you find in the internet. A good hash function provides as few collisions as possible for your specific inputs.

A general purpose hash function may be sub-optimal in your specific case. A hash function specifically designed for some inputs (and this may very well be such a function) may work significantly worse on *your* inputs.