# What is the default hash function used in C++ std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stl, unordered-map

I am using

```
unordered_map<string, int>
```

and

```
unordered_map<int, int>
```

What hash function is used in each case and what is chance of collision in each case?
I will be inserting unique string and unique int as keys in each case respectively.

I am interested in knowing the algorithm of hash function in case of string and int keys and their collision stats.

Comment: I think it's up to the standard.  Not sure what an unorderd_map is.

Comment: unordered_map is like hash table...Did default hash functions change in C++98 vs C++11?

Comment: You tagged this C++11, but asked about TR1.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry @John Dibling, I tagged it C++11. I've edited the title too since I think the question has more meaning that way; now answers can refer to a formal standard. Do feel free to change back; I see you have more experience on this site than I do.

Comment: Then why are you referring to the `tr1` namespace?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The function object [`std::hash<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) is used.

Standard specializations exist for all built-in types, and some other standard library types 
such as `std::string` and `std::thread`. See the link for the full list.

For other types to be used in a `std::unordered_map`, you will have to specialize `std::hash<>` or create your own function object.

The chance of collision is completely implementation-dependent, but considering the fact that integers are limited between a defined range, while strings are theoretically infinitely long, I'd say there is a much better chance for collision with strings.

As for the implementation in GCC, the specialization for builtin-types just returns the bit pattern. Here's how they are defined in `bits/functional_hash.h`:

```
  /// Partial specializations for pointer types.
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct hash<_Tp*> : public __hash_base<size_t, _Tp*>
    {
      size_t
      operator()(_Tp* __p) const noexcept
      { return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(__p); }
    };

  // Explicit specializations for integer types.
#define _Cxx_hashtable_define_trivial_hash(_Tp)     \
  template<>                        \
    struct hash<_Tp> : public __hash_base<size_t, _Tp>  \
    {                                                   \
      size_t                                            \
      operator()(_Tp __val) const noexcept              \
      { return static_cast<size_t>(__val); }            \
    };

  /// Explicit specialization for bool.
  _Cxx_hashtable_define_trivial_hash(bool)

  /// Explicit specialization for char.
  _Cxx_hashtable_define_trivial_hash(char)

  /// ...
```

---

The specialization for `std::string` is defined as:

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_COMPATIBILITY_CXX0X
  /// std::hash specialization for string.
  template<>
    struct hash<string>
    : public __hash_base<size_t, string>
    {
      size_t
      operator()(const string& __s) const noexcept
      { return std::_Hash_impl::hash(__s.data(), __s.length()); }
    };
```

Some further search leads us to:

```
struct _Hash_impl
{
  static size_t
  hash(const void* __ptr, size_t __clength,
       size_t __seed = static_cast<size_t>(0xc70f6907UL))
  { return _Hash_bytes(__ptr, __clength, __seed); }
  ...
};
...
// Hash function implementation for the nontrivial specialization.
// All of them are based on a primitive that hashes a pointer to a
// byte array. The actual hash algorithm is not guaranteed to stay
// the same from release to release -- it may be updated or tuned to
// improve hash quality or speed.
size_t
_Hash_bytes(const void* __ptr, size_t __len, size_t __seed);
```

`_Hash_bytes` is an external function from `libstdc++`. A bit more searching led me to [this file](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/libsupc%2b%2b/hash_bytes.cc;hb=HEAD), which states:

```
// This file defines Hash_bytes, a primitive used for defining hash
// functions. Based on public domain MurmurHashUnaligned2, by Austin
// Appleby.  http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/
```

So the default hashing algorithm GCC uses for strings is MurmurHashUnaligned2.

Comment: I am interested in knowing the algorithm of hash function in case of string and int keys and their collision stats.

Comment: @Medicine: It's not specified by the standard, it's up to the library implementation to decide the best way to go about that. You'll have to look at your local implementation. For example, this answer now includes GCC's particular choices.

Comment: @Medicine: The default hash algorithm for Visual Studio (as of VS2012) is [`Fowler–Noll–Vo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) (FNV-1a).

Comment: Thanks @Avidanborisov my strings are all unique and are between 14 to 21 size comprising english-alphabets _ numbers

Comment: Link to [MurmurHash](https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/) source code. Also available on [github](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash2.cpp).

Comment: @Medicine While libc++ uses murmur2 or city hash. see [__do_string_hash](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__string#L854)

Comment: @Avidan Borisov: You probably meant specialization of `std::hash` for `std::thread::id`. Thread objects themselves are not hashable.

Comment: If the default hash for built-in types is just the original bit pattern, then what's the function that compresses that into an index for the hash table?  You can't just slice a few bits off the bottom like you would a traditional hash.

Comment: I tried it in godbolt and it looks like it's just `key % table_size`.  Seems a bit collision-prone, but maybe the table size is cleverly chosen to mitigate that.

Answer (score 21):

### GCC C++11 uses "MurmurHashUnaligned2", by Austin Appleby

Though the hashing algorithms are compiler-dependent, I'll present it for GCC C++11. [@Avidan Borisov astutely discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411888/4561887) that the GCC hashing algorithm used for strings is "MurmurHashUnaligned2," by Austin Appleby. I did some searching and found a mirrored copy of GCC on Github. Therefore:

**The GCC C++11 hashing functions used for [`unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) (a hash table template) and [`unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) (a hash set template) appear to be as follows.**

- [Thanks to Avidan Borisov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411888/4561887) for his background research which on the question of *what are the GCC C++11 hash functions used*, stating that GCC uses an implementation of "MurmurHashUnaligned2", by Austin Appleby (see http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/ and https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher).
- In the file "gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/hash_bytes.cc", here (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/hash_bytes.cc), I found the implementations. Here's the one for the "32-bit size_t" return value, for example (pulled 11 Aug 2017)

Code:

```
// Implementation of Murmur hash for 32-bit size_t.
size_t _Hash_bytes(const void* ptr, size_t len, size_t seed)
{
  const size_t m = 0x5bd1e995;
  size_t hash = seed ^ len;
  const char* buf = static_cast<const char*>(ptr);

  // Mix 4 bytes at a time into the hash.
  while (len >= 4)
  {
    size_t k = unaligned_load(buf);
    k *= m;
    k ^= k >> 24;
    k *= m;
    hash *= m;
    hash ^= k;
    buf += 4;
    len -= 4;
  }

  // Handle the last few bytes of the input array.
  switch (len)
  {
    case 3:
      hash ^= static_cast<unsigned char>(buf[2]) << 16;
      [[gnu::fallthrough]];
    case 2:
      hash ^= static_cast<unsigned char>(buf[1]) << 8;
      [[gnu::fallthrough]];
    case 1:
      hash ^= static_cast<unsigned char>(buf[0]);
      hash *= m;
  };

  // Do a few final mixes of the hash.
  hash ^= hash >> 13;
  hash *= m;
  hash ^= hash >> 15;
  return hash;
}
```

#### The latest version of Austin Appleby's hashing functions is "MurmurHash3", which is released into the *public domain!*

Austin states [in his readme](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher):

> The SMHasher suite also includes **MurmurHash3**, which is the latest version in the series of MurmurHash functions - the new version is faster, more robust, and its variants can produce 32- and 128-bit hash values efficiently on both x86 and x64 platforms.

For MurmurHash3's source code, see here:

1. [MurmurHash3.h](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash3.h)
2. [MurmurHash3.cpp](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash3.cpp)

And the great thing is!? It's *public domain* software. That's right! The tops of the files state:

> ```
> // MurmurHash3 was written by Austin Appleby, and is placed in the public
> // domain. The author hereby disclaims copyright to this source code.
> ```

So, if you'd like to use MurmurHash3 in your open source software, personal projects, or proprietary software, including for implementing your own hash tables in C, go for it!

If you'd like build instructions to build and test his MurmurHash3 code, I've written some here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/smhasher/blob/add_build_instructions/build/README.md. Hopefully [this PR I've opened](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/pull/88) gets accepted and then they will end up in his main repo. But, until then, refer to the build instructions in my fork.

### For additional hashing functions, including `djb2`, and the 2 versions of the K&R hashing functions...

...(one apparently terrible, one pretty good), see my other answer here: [hash function for string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666509/hash-function-for-string/45641002#45641002).

### See also:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash
2. Further study to do: take a look at these hash function speed benchmarks: https://github.com/fredrikwidlund/hash-function-benchmark (thanks @lfmunoz [for pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411742/what-is-the-default-hash-function-used-in-c-stdunordered-map/45641982?noredirect=1#comment125401482_45641982))

Comment: https://github.com/fredrikwidlund/hash-function-benchmark
benchmark includes MurmerHash3 and regular C++ 11 hash. There is a big difference in performance measured. Which doesn't make sense if both use same algorithm

Comment: @lfmunoz, thanks for sharing the benchmark. They are not the same algorithms though. GCC's implementation of C++11 uses `MurmurHashUnaligned2`. `MurmerHash3` is a separate algorithm, also by Austin Appleby. They are not the same algorithm. `MurmerHash3` is his latest and greatest work, and is not part of GCC's C++11. I would assume `MurmerHash3` is better (in speed) than Murmer Hash 2 or else there'd be little or no point in releasing it as a follow-on, unless it was a tradeoff and it was slower perhaps but had some other advantages such as better distribution of buckets and fewer collisions.

Comment: @lfmunoz, also, the top of that benchmark chart says `clang v3.6.0`. That means they are _not_ using the GCC compiler, so I can't say what hash algorithm they are using. It could be something entirely different. You'd have to go pull the source code for that version of the clang compiler and see.

Comment: Spelling fixes: `MurmerHash3` should be `MurmurHash3` (e --> u).