# quick access of hash function (without using string object)

Tags: c++, hash

The following code [snippet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) can do hash value on a string object. I would like to get hash value a binary string (a pointer and length). I know I can form a string object with pointer and length, but there is  extra overhead to form a string only for that.    Wonder if it's possible to use the std hash function with two parameters: pointer and length.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Meet the new boss...";
    std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;
    std::size_t str_hash = hash_fn(str);

    std::cout << str_hash << '\n';
}
```

Comment: specialise std::hash for a custom class that holds a pointer and a length?

Comment: Thanks @RichardHodges for the comment,  do you eventually need to call `std::hash<string>()` to get the hash value?

Comment: @codingFun - You might want to look at [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639305/597607) to see how much time you save by not constructing a short `std::string` - about 1 ns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this article in stack overflow which shows that the underlying hash function is actually a function of the bytes in the string's internal buffer:

[What is the default hash function used in C++ std::unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411742/what-is-the-default-hash-function-used-in-c-stdunordered-map)

But rather than risk undefined behaviour by calling into internal functions within the standard library, why not ask the question, "how much performance will I lose by creating a `std::string`"? Given that you can always create such a string as a `static const` (zero overhead) I wonder what you're actually going to save?

Comment: Thanks @RichardHodges for the link.   Just tried,  I can directly use:  `std::_Hash_impl::hash(const char*, int size)`.    :-)

Comment: Gah! You can today but there's no guarantee it will work on all systems or even on the next release of the library. It seems a little knowledge is a dangerous thing...

Comment: Agree. There is a trade off for everything :-)  Thanks again.