# In std::unordered_map, how to iterate over hashes?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, std, unordered-map

The `std::unordered_map` has hash-value for each key. What is the way to obtain those hash values?

What for? To evaluate relevance of a hash function to the data set. I could just generate hashes from outside, but I might not have access to the hash function used.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [What is the default hash function used in C++ std::unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19411742/11082165) and [terate keys in a C++ map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1443793/11082165)

Comment: _"unordered_map should store hashes per each key"_ isn't quite right. Hash maps don't usually store the actual hash values of the keys, since that would be redundant. The best you'll be able to do is iterate the keys and compute the associated hash for each one.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I might not have access to the hash function used."*

There is access to the hash function used:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::unordered_map<int, int> my_map = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
    const auto hasher{ my_map.hash_function() };

    for (const auto& [key, value] : my_map) { // Structured bindings were introduced in C++17

        const auto hash_value = hasher(key);

        std::cout << "(h: " << hash_value << ", k: " << key << ", v: " << value << ")   ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Y4h5VNhuz)

> *"To evaluate relevance of a hash function to the data set."*

It is possible to provide a custom hash function for `std::unordered_map` by passing a different `Hash` class to its constructor.