# VStudio SDL complains about bitmask unsigned type for CRC32 function

Tags: c++

I need to use a very basic CRC32 function (preferably without lookout table) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001712/1134813)(as others on that original page) looks perfect. On all platform gcc does not signal any errors/warnings even with higher warning levels, but on Windows SDL complains. Even if I disable SDL(I don't know if I should do this) I am stuck with warning C4146.

```
mask = -(crc & 1); //crc is unsigned int
warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
```

What is the best practice in this situation, should I disable SDL and then "#pragma warning" the warning for this line? Should I modify the CRC32 function?

Thanks :)

Comment: It is defined see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Unary_arithmetic_operators

Comment: Yes, I saw...but can you detail more your answer, please?:)

Comment: Having first verified that the crc function works correctly, you should disable that warning in that code only, but leave it active elsewhere.

Comment: I found a version that replaces the problematic line (and the one after it) with this `crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (crc & 1 ? 0xEDB88320 : 0);` and it seems to produce the same result

Comment: LE: silly me, I can replace `mask = -(crc & 1)` with `mask = (-1)*(crc & 1)`, it's the same thing and it works like a charm. :-)