# hash code no working

Tags: c, hash

I found this Hash function written in Java and with some help from stackoverflow converted it to C.  The problem is it gives a different hash value each time it runs on the same word.

Here's the original function:

```
long sfold(String s, int M) 
{
  int intLength = s.length() / 4;
  long sum = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < intLength; j++) 
  {
     char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
     long mult = 1;
     for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) 
     {
        sum += c[k] * mult;
        mult *= 256;
     }
  }

  char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
  long mult = 1;
  for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) 
  {
     sum += c[k] * mult;
     mult *= 256;
  }

  return(Math.abs(sum) % M);
 }
```

And here's how we rewrote it:

```
include <stdlib.h>
include <stdio.h>
include <math.h>
include <string.h>

long sfold(char * s, int M);

int main(void)
{
    char *  s = "test";
    int M;
    long x;
    M = 525;
    x = sfold(s,M);

    printf("%ld\n",x);
}   
long sfold(char * s, int M)
{
    int intLength = strlen(s) / 4;
    long sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < intLength; j++) 
    {
       char c[4];
       memcpy(c, s + 4 * j, 4);

       //char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
       long mult = 1;

       for (int k = 0; k < strlen(c); k++) 
       {
           sum += c[k] * mult;
           mult *= 256;
       }
    }

    char c[intLength];
    memcpy(c,s,intLength);
    //char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
    long mult = 1;

    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(c); k++) 
    {
       sum += c[k] * mult;
       mult *= 256;
    }

    return(abs(sum) % M);
}
```

Shouldn't this give the same value each time we run the program?  Anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, line by line.

Comment: `strlen(c)` : `c` is not terminated with NUL('\0').

Comment: The original has `intLength * 4` not  `char c[intLength];` Also strlen is of course usless as BLUEPIXY states.

Comment: _Congratulations !_ you **luckily** invoked a UB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that string copying is really silly. What's the point of copying if all you need is the character value?

Here's how it might look in C:

```
long sfold(char* s, unsigned long M) {
   unsigned long mult = 1, sum = 0;
   while (*s) {
      sum += (uint8_t)(*s++) * mult;
      mult *= 256;
      if (!mult) mult = 1;
   }
   return sum % M;
}
```

But it's a terrible hash algorithm. You'd be better off with a simple modular hash (which is also not great, but it's not as bad):

```
/* This could be any small prime */
static const unsigned long mult = 31;
long sfold(char* s, unsigned long M) {
   /* Avoid having the hash of the empty string be 0 */
   unsigned long sum = 0xBEA00D1FUL;
   while (*s)
      sum += (uint8_t)(*s++) * mult;
   return sum % M;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I took care of most of the bugs for you. I made it C99 compliant, mainly out of habit. The major problem was using `strlen(c)`: `c` is a character array, not a string (which is a character array terminated with the null `'\0'` character). You'll need to rewrite your function so that if `calloc()`/`malloc()` fails, the function terminates with an error. Or you can go back to variable length arrays like you were using before if your compiler supports it. [There are likely better hash functions in other posts on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666509/hash-function-for-string), but this at least helps you getting yours working in a deterministic manner without invoking undefined behavior.

**Code Listing**

---

```
/******************************************************************************/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE  (4)

/******************************************************************************/
long sfold(const char* s, int M);

/******************************************************************************/
int main(void) {
   const char*  s = "test string";
   int M;
   long x;
   M = 525;
   x = sfold(s,M);

   printf("String:%s - Hash:%ld\n", s, x);
}

/******************************************************************************/
long sfold(const char* s, int M) {
   int intLength = strlen(s) / 4;
   char* c = calloc(intLength, sizeof(char));   /* Warning, test if c==NULL, this
                                                 * call can fail.
                                                 */
   long sum = 0;
   int j, k;

   for (j=0; j<intLength; j++) {
      char c[BUF_SIZE];
      memcpy(c, s + BUF_SIZE * j, BUF_SIZE);

      //char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
      long mult = 1;

      for (k=0; k<BUF_SIZE; k++) {
         sum += c[k] * mult;
         mult *= 256;
      }
   }

   memcpy(c, s, intLength);
   //char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
   long mult = 1;

   for (k=0; k<BUF_SIZE; k++) {
      sum += c[k] * mult;
      mult *= 256;
   }

   free(c);
   return(abs(sum) % M);
}
```

**Sample Output**

---

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo $i; ./a.out; done
1
String:test string - Hash:384
2
String:test string - Hash:384
3
String:test string - Hash:384
4
String:test string - Hash:384
5
String:test string - Hash:384
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I run valgrind I get: valgrind ./test2
==345== Command: ./test2
==345== 
==345== Invalid read of size 1
==345==    at 0x80486F2: sfold (test2.c:50)
==345==    by 0x80485B7: main (test2.c:18)
==345==  Address 0x423c02a is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==345==    at 0x402C109: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==345==    by 0x804862E: sfold (test2.c:26)
==345==    by 0x80485B7: main (test2.c:18)
==345== 




==345== 
==345== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: @DCR also, please take into consideration the points rici made in his/her answer: they are very valid points.

Comment: Also note that this hash function (like your attempt) does not do the same as the original hash function, which first processes all 4-byte chunks and then treats the remaining bytes in an extra loop. This code has the substring wrong. It passes over the 4-byte chunks twice, once with a 4.-byte stride and then in a single byte stride. The present code will give the same hash value for all words with fewer than 4 letters, for example, namely 0.