# Hash function is not giving desire results

Tags: c, hash

I am implementing hash function in order to check the anagrams, but I am not getting desired output. Could you suggest what went wrong?

Output:

```
key[148]:val[joy]
key[174]:val[jam]
key[294]:val[paula]
key[13]:val[ulrich]
key[174]:val[cat]
key[174]:val[act]
key[148]:val[yoj]
key[265]:val[vij]
key[265]:val[jiv]
```

Here key value `174` is fine for strings `act` and `cat` (anagrams) but same can't be expected with `jam`.

Below is the code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long hash(char *str, size_t size) {
    unsigned long hash_val = 5381;
    unsigned long sum = 0;
    char *val;
    int i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        val = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        memset(val, '\0', strlen(str) + 1);
        strcpy(val, str);

        for (i = 0; val[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            sum = sum + val[i];
        }
        return size % sum;
    }
}

int main() {
   int i;
   char *str[9] = { "joy", "jam", "paula", "ulrich","cat", "act","yoj", "vij", "jiv" };
   unsigned long key;
   size_t size = 4542; // it may be anything just for test it is being used
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        key = hash(str[i], size);
        printf("\nkey[%ld]:val[%s]", key, str[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why down votes for the same. I was expecting the resolution of this problem. I know what are the pitfalls of  current approach so was just expecting proper solution of this issue not down votes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can, because your hash function is very poorly written - it returns your constant 'size' variable modulo sum of all the string characters.

The problem is that the sum of ASCII codes 'c' + 'a' + 't' is equal to the 'j' + 'a' + 'm' (equal to 312) so you are getting the same value for your 'hash'.

You could use a 'normal' (e.g. polynomial) hash function for your anagram table, but with sorted strings - that would be the easiest approach.

For another method, you can calculate a number of appearances of each letter in the string (a histogram) and hash (or just store as is) them instead.

I recommend you to do some research on this topic as it's a very common task.

Also, you could just sort the strings and let `unordered_set<string>` do the job for you.

Comment: do you have any algorithm for the same?

Comment: @pri yes, as I said, you can use any hashing algorithm, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666509/hash-function-for-string but sort a string before you calculate the hash

Comment: humm. I was aware of this link but didn't think about the sorting , thanks for your help. +1 from my end as well to you.

Answer (score 2):

> *but same can't be expected with jam.*

Well, there you go wrong. Let's see your algo. What you're doing is basically summing up the ASCII value of the elements of the strings, and returning the modulus result of a fixed value taken with respect to the sum.

To elaborate, as per the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/),

```
j == 106
a == 97
m == 109
```

and

```
c == 99
a == 97
t == 116
```

Both the words end up having a sum result of `312`. 
Now as per your algo,

```
 4542 % 312
```

is suppose to give a *constant* value, right? That is what it is giving.

Now, don't be `"sad"`, as

```
s == 115
a ==97
d == 100
```

that also comes up with `312`.

That said, I see you have a local variable `unsigned long hash_val = 5381;` defined inside your function, but used nowhere.

Comment: Thanks for your observation.currently there is no use of that hash_val in my implementation. I also had also performed  the sum of ASCII values and found that sum will be same for cat and jam but is there anyway to improve this algorithm as i don't want to perform additional check for  similar sum values in order to make them different.

Answer (score 0):

Your hash function has many problems:

- The `for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)` loop is completely useless.
- It is utterly inadequate to allocate memory for a copy of the string, and to forget to free it! Just use the string directly.
- You summing method has too many easy collisions, as you diagnosed: anagrams produce the same sum, but also many simple words.  You should shuffle the sum between before each character value is added.
- `return size % sum;` should really be `return sum % size;` so the return value can be used as an index into the hash table of size `size`. As a matter of fact, `size % sum` would invoke undefined behavior if `sum` happened to compute to `0`, which would require a very long string (>16MB) but is possible.

Here is an improved hash function:

```
#include <limits.h>

// constraints: str != NULL, size > 0
size_t hash(const char *str, size_t size) {
    size_t sum = 5381;  // initial salt
    while (*str != '\0') {
        // rotate the current sum 2 places to the left
        sum = (sum << 2) | (sum >> (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(sum) - 2));
        // add the next character value
        sum += (unsigned char)*str++;
    }
    return sum % size;
}
```