# how to signature a string to generate a uint64 value?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, sign

I want a function like this:

```
uint64 sign(String s) {
    // how to signature a string
}
```

For use, this function can accept any string and return a signature. For example,

```
uint64 a = sign("hello world")
```

This function should signature a string just depending on its plain text but not memory location. And, different string text should generate different uint64 values.

Comment: What you are looking for is usually called a hash function. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666509/hash-function-for-string.

Comment: Different strings should ALWAYS generate different uint64 values?  This isn't really possible.  Think about how many different strings there are, and how many different uint64s there are.