# Implementation of hash algorithm converts string to number

Tags: c, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I have to implement hash table,
I got scheme that shows how to convert string to number (hash function):

```
abcdef... -> ((256*a+b) XOR (256*c+d)) XOR (256*e+f) ...
```

I'm writing this question, because I'm not sure if this code (mainly loops) works in a proper way.

```
int hash(char *s){
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i, result = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len-1; i=i+2) {
            result ^= ((256*s[i])+s[i+1]);
    }
    if(s[i]!=0) {
            result ^= (256*s[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666509/hash-function-for-string

Comment: Generated a lot of collisions for me using string permutations.  Unless you really need to reinvent the wheel use a proven hash function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash functions technically belong to the branch of Cryptography, this has to do with the (questionable) definition and the (strict) requirements of the Hashing.

Hence, it's highly recommended that you don't roll your own hashing algorithm and stick to existing (tested) algorithms that minimize collisions.

Converting a string to a number isn't hashing... although it's probably a good way to experience collisions and ending up with untraceable issues when you think you came up with a unique value...

Unless this isn't a school assignment where you were given some stub "hash" algorithm that's actually meant to satisfy an assignment (and not a real life implementation), try looking up real hashing algorithm. All of them come with pseudo code and most of them come with the C implementations that were used for testing.

For example, [SipHash](https://131002.net/siphash/) is a very common string hashing algorithm used in some standard libraries (i.e. Ruby and Rust).

Good Luck!

**EDIT**

Some people believe that using cryptographic hash functions is sub optimal. You should consider your use case, but... If you are using the hash to assume equity, I would suggest paying the performance price. If you're using the hash as an unsafe indicator, it might not matter.

Here's [a page with some non-cryptographic hash functions](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html).

P.S.

Here's an implementation I wrote for the SipHash I mentioned... My code isn't well tested, so if you find any issues, feel free to [post them here](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/master/src/bscrypt/bscrypt/siphash.c).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SIPHASH_DEFAULT_KEY                         \
  (uint64_t[]) { 0x0706050403020100, 0x0f0e0d0c0b0a0908 }

uint64_t siphash24(const void *data, size_t len, uint64_t iv_key[2]);

// clang-format off
#if !defined(__BIG_ENDIAN__) && !defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
#   if defined(__has_include)
#     if __has_include(<endian.h>)
#      include <endian.h>
#     elif __has_include(<sys/endian.h>)
#      include <sys/endian.h>
#     endif
#   endif
#   if !defined(__BIG_ENDIAN__) && !defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__) && \
                __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
#      define __BIG_ENDIAN__
#   endif
#endif

#ifndef __unused
#   define __unused __attribute__((unused))
#endif
// clang-format on

/** 64Bit left rotation, inlined. */
#define _lrot64(i, bits)                                                       \
  (((uint64_t)(i) << (bits)) | ((uint64_t)(i) >> (64 - (bits))))

#ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__
/* the algorithm was designed as little endian */
/** inplace byte swap 64 bit integer */
#define sip_local64(i)                                                         \
  (((i)&0xFFULL) << 56) | (((i)&0xFF00ULL) << 40) |                            \
      (((i)&0xFF0000ULL) << 24) | (((i)&0xFF000000ULL) << 8) |                 \
      (((i)&0xFF00000000ULL) >> 8) | (((i)&0xFF0000000000ULL) >> 24) |         \
      (((i)&0xFF000000000000ULL) >> 40) | (((i)&0xFF00000000000000ULL) >> 56)

#else
/** no need */
#define sip_local64(i) (i)
#endif

uint64_t siphash24(const void *data, size_t len, uint64_t iv_key[2]) {
  /* initialize the 4 words */
  uint64_t v0 = iv_key[0] ^ 0x736f6d6570736575ULL;
  uint64_t v1 = iv_key[1] ^ 0x646f72616e646f6dULL;
  uint64_t v2 = iv_key[0] ^ 0x6c7967656e657261ULL;
  uint64_t v3 = iv_key[1] ^ 0x7465646279746573ULL;
  const uint64_t *w64 = data;
  uint8_t len_mod = len & 255;
  union {
    uint64_t i;
    uint8_t str[8];
  } word;

#define _bs_map_SipRound                                                       \
  do {                                                                         \
    v2 += v3;                                                                  \
    v3 = _lrot64(v3, 16) ^ v2;                                                 \
    v0 += v1;                                                                  \
    v1 = _lrot64(v1, 13) ^ v0;                                                 \
    v0 = _lrot64(v0, 32);                                                      \
    v2 += v1;                                                                  \
    v0 += v3;                                                                  \
    v1 = _lrot64(v1, 17) ^ v2;                                                 \
    v3 = _lrot64(v3, 21) ^ v0;                                                 \
    v2 = _lrot64(v2, 32);                                                      \
  } while (0);

  while (len >= 8) {
    word.i = sip_local64(*w64);
    v3 ^= word.i;
    /* Sip Rounds */
    _bs_map_SipRound;
    _bs_map_SipRound;
    v0 ^= word.i;
    w64 += 1;
    len -= 8;
  }
  word.i = 0;
  uint8_t *pos = word.str;
  uint8_t *w8 = (void *)w64;
  switch (len) {
  case 7:
    pos[6] = w8[6];
  case 6:
    pos[5] = w8[5];
  case 5:
    pos[4] = w8[4];
  case 4:
    pos[3] = w8[3];
  case 3:
    pos[2] = w8[2];
  case 2:
    pos[1] = w8[1];
  case 1:
    pos[0] = w8[0];
  }
  word.str[7] = len_mod;
  // word.i = sip_local64(word.i);

  /* last round */
  v3 ^= word.i;
  _bs_map_SipRound;
  _bs_map_SipRound;
  v0 ^= word.i;
  /* Finalization */
  v2 ^= 0xff;
  /* d iterations of SipRound */
  _bs_map_SipRound;
  _bs_map_SipRound;
  _bs_map_SipRound;
  _bs_map_SipRound;
  /* XOR it all together */
  v0 ^= v1 ^ v2 ^ v3;
#undef _bs_map_SipRound
  return v0;
}

#undef sip_local64
#undef _lrot64
```

(the `switch` case fall through is intentional)